# keep the current page changes before actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Ok guys, this may be a stupid question, I can not search any related issue, perhaps it is not a problem

for ex. I have a nav menu in my mvc 4 app like this

`@Html.ActionLink("Driver", "Index", "Driver")`

`@Html.ActionLink("Vehicle", "Index", "Vehicle")`

in Driver controller index Get I have a model from database and display everything in view, user make change something without submit and click menu actionlink to go to Vehicle page, and then goes back Driver page again.

what I want is in driver index page I can keep the last changes and display it, but in driver controll index GET I have to get everything from database, since I don't have post to save last change to tempdata.

any ideas? thank you very much

update: Thanks Philip very much about the answer, but still a little bit problem.
since ActionLink happens before $(window).unload, if I sumbmit a post to server in jQuery, the postback will lose the direction.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to catch the `onbeforeunload` event and check if the user has made modifications to the model.

If there are changes, you could save these in the browsers [local or session storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) (HTML5) or post them to the server (web service).

On the next reload of the page you have to check the storage or ask the server for the model.

```
(function ($) {
    var isDirty = false;

    $(function(){
        // check local/session storage OR fetch data from server.
    });

    $(':input').change(function () {
        isDirty = true;
    });

    $(window).unload(function () {
        if (isDirty) {
            // store changes in local/session storage OR post them to the server.
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Philip, it is a great answer